# What is the function of provided dataset?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

```
 x | y
 0 | 0
 1 | 1
 2 | 1
 3 | 2 
 4 | 2
 5 | 2
 6 | 3
 7 | 3 
 8 | 3
 9 | 3
10 | 4
11 | 4
12 | 4
13 | 4
14 | 4
15 | 5
16 | 5
17 | 5
18 | 5
19 | 5
20 | 5
```

Desmos url: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mwnivlqhfl

Pattern seems easy recognizable, but i can't figure out function $y = f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ the points such that $f(x) = k$ are only those in $\Big[\frac{k(k+1)}{2};\frac{k(k+3)}{2}\Big]$.
Now, let $a = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}, b = \frac{k(k+3)}{2}$: to find the inverse you have to solve for $k$
$$\begin{cases}
a = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \\
b = \frac{k(k+3)}{2}
\end{cases}$$
Simple algebra caluli lead to
$$\begin{cases}
k = \frac{\sqrt{8a+1}-1}{2}\\
k = \frac{\sqrt{8a+9}-3}{6}
\end{cases}$$
but you can rewrite those expression by noticing that the image (arrival set of function) is $\mathbb{N}$, and retrieve
$$\begin{cases}
k = \Big\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8a+1}-3}{2} \Big\rfloor+1\\
k = \Big\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8b+1}-3}{2} \Big\rfloor+1
\end{cases}$$
hence
$$f(x)=\Big\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8x+1}-3}{2} \Big\rfloor+1$$

Comment: How do you know it holds for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I think that there are hypothesis *hidden* by the user .. *pattern seems easy recognizable* and all values are integers led to that tought

Comment: can't fully understand this step: `but you can rewrite those expression by noticing that the image (arrival set of function) is NN, and retrieve` but function works, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=\left \lfloor  \frac{\sqrt{8x+1}-3}{2} \right \rfloor +1$$ does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This surely looks like $f(x) = \lfloor g(x) \rfloor$ kind of chart and the fact that it knows the previous state suggests that it keeps history so it might be recursive in that sense. this leads to something like 
$$
x > 0: f(x) = \lfloor g(f(x-1)) \rfloor \\
x = 0: f(x) = 0 \\
x < 0: f(x) = undefined
$$
In the light of thatsince the jump from one scale to other is also one this suggests the following:
$$
x > 0: f(x) = \lfloor g(f(x-1)) \rfloor + 1\\
x = 0: f(x) = 0 \\
x < 0: f(x) = undefined
$$
Since f is recursive, it can consist of other recursive functions such as $\Sigma$. So I think a function that satisfies the data set would be something like:
$$
f(x): max(y) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} ; \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y \leq x
$$

PS: I wrote the states of problem solving in this case.